# Most of the code I read does not override equals(), hashCode() and other Object methods. Is it Normal?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I know this looks like a question asked many times, so let me get more specific:

If I pass my objects to third party code, it may need my objects to have overriden the Object methods. There is no way to be sure unless the third party is open source.

But most of the code I read is missing thoses overrides.

Am I correct in saying that, even if a code doesn't ***directly*** need a correct equals() or hashCode(), as long as it passes its object to a black box third party, it is still risky?

Edit: As many have pointed out, there are cases where not overriding makes sense: basically when we are satisfied with the parent implementation (this including the Object default one, which tends to be good when our object is not a "data" representation). Also we know that some methods from the JDK need thoses override.

But in my case, if I take a recent exemple, I had pojos that were the object representation of a JSON hierarchy. I was then passing thoses objects to a third party library to generate the JSON (and then sending it to some REST ws). What tells me that this third party didn't need the Object methods overrides? I suppose a good API would indicate when it needs objects being passed to it to be overriding hashCode() and the like, since people are likely to oversee this issue.

Comment: When people are trying to write code fast and get things written, these are usually overlooked and the default behavior (equals is reference equality, hashcode is from the object's address iirc) then takes over. If you're not putting them in collections (as a comparable or a key), you don't need either unless you're doing any kind of comparisons between objects

Comment: But a lot relies on equals and hash code. As soon as you want to put the elements e.g. in a `List` and do something like `contains()` you need it.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the objects. Many times, the library you are working with does not need to compare objects, as they each represent something different, that doesn't have an equivalence concept. If each individual instance is considered different than any others, then there is no need for these methods.

Comment: `As soon as you want to put the elements e.g. in a List and do something like contains() you need it.` no, depends entirely on the use case. Sometimes reference-equality is desired.

Comment: Another thought: `equals/hashcode` is a concept related to *data*, and classes in Java do not always represent data. There can be non-static classes, even several of them, which are just *logic*. Examples are most classes you inject into other classes in order to encapsulate their logic, mock it, etc. These classes are instantiated and likely have instance variables themselves, but they're still part of logic, as opposed to data, and therefore probably don't need to be comparable.

Comment: *"There is no way to be sure unless the third party is open source."* If they are properly documented, then you can know by reading the documentation. If a third-party library requires your objects to override equals and hashCode, but the documentation doesn't say so, then that library is not properly documented.